# Описание структуры pcap файла

Tags: c++, парсер, pcap

Stackoverflow. Начал разрабатывать pcap парсер без использования чего-либо готового(имеется ввиду готовые либы по типу pcaplib, pcapPlusPlus). Начал искать спецификацию pcap формата, но единственно, что нашел - описание глобального заголовка, описание пакетного заголовка и общую структуру, то есть
global header - packet header - packet data - packet header...
Единственное, что сказано про packet data - это то, что состоит из количества бит описанных в packet header и то, что packet data начинается сразу после  packet header.
Но так и не смог найти описание packet data и спецификацию.
Прошу помочь разобраться с тем из чего состоит packet data, всегда ли он состоит из одних и тех же структур, то есть насобирать как можно больше информации о packet data.
P.S. обыскал как англоязычный веб, так и русский.

Answer (score 0):

packet data содержит данные полученного из сети пакета, поэтому там могут быть заголовки самых разных протоколов. Если вы их хотите разбирать сами, то нужно найти их описание в интернете и начать разбор с верхнего уровня и потом опускаться всё ниже и ниже. Формат заголовков в файле зависит от поля LinkType в global header.

Список значений LinkType можно посмотреть по ссылке:
https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html

А описание формата PCAP по ссылке:
https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-gharris-opsawg-pcap-00.html

Comment: Добрый день, зависимость от linktype не понятна, так как это поле global header, но linktype может же быть разным для каждого пакета?

Comment: Нет, LinkType в File Header (он же global header) один и тот же для всех пакетов данного файла и  это протокол самого верхнего уровня для всех пакетов внутри данного файла. А вот если его разбирать в каждом пакете, то внутри него мы получим различия между пакетами.

Comment: Например, если я захватываю пакеты на Linux на сетевом интерфейсе any, то для всех пакетов моего файла LinkType = 25 (Linux cooked-mode capture, https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL#:~:text=Linux%20cooked%2Dmode%20capture%20(SLL,or%20can't%20be%20used), который я могу разобрать для каждого пакета и выяснить какие именно протоколы содержатся внутри конкретного пакета.

Comment: А, например, если я захватываю пакеты на проводном сетевом интерфейск, то у меня LinkType = 1 ( Ethernet), который я могу дальше разобрать и для каждого пакета выяснить что там внутри (например, сначала IP, а ниже TCP или UDP и так далее). При захвате на ,беспроводном интерфейсе LinkType = 23 (IEEE 802.11), который я тоже могу разобрать.